# Implementation Status of "identifier" Keyword

Tags: keyword, d

Using DMD 2.057, I cannot get the following code to compile:

```
import std.stdio;

import std.array;

enum direction
{
    test1,
    test2,
    test3
}

string getDescriptionOnConnect(direction d)
{
    string descriptionOnConnect = "Going in direction %dir%";
    foreach(s; __traits(allMembers, direction))
    {
        if (identifier(d) == s)
        {
            descriptionOnConnect = 
                replace(descriptionOnConnect, "%dir%", identifier(d)); 
        }
    }

    return descriptionOnConnect;
}   

int main(string[] argv)
{
   return 0;
}
```

I get the error `Error: undefined identifier identifier`, although this keyword is clearly defined in the documentation at http://www.d-programming-language.org/traits.html#identifier. I also tried `__identifier`, but I got the same error. Has this not been implemented yet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`identifier` is an argument to `__traits` just like `allMembers` (as are all the others on that page).

Comment: in other words use `__traits(identifier, d)`